# Using IFTTT to trigger email notification to group of recipients

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, if-this-then-that

Can I set up IFTTT to send notification emails to a Google Contact group whenever an article is posted to a Blogger blog (private)?

Comment: Are you an admin for this particular Blogger blog?

Comment: yes, i'm admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you really want is to send an email to a group of addresses when a new blog post gets published, I suggest you do not use IFTTT for that. Do this instead:

1. Set up a Google Group and add all the addresses that you want to receive the email. Make sure `no-reply@blogger.com` can send mail to the group.
2. Go to your blog's **Settings** → **Mobile and email** and add the Google Group email address to the *Email posts to* section.

Comment: do the group of people need to have goole accounts for this?

Comment: No, the recipients do not need Google accounts. And you don't have to use Google Groups for this. You can use any mailing list service to create a list, or even add your recipients directly to your blog settings.

Comment: ..didn't know that! I'll give it a try. many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a couple of difficulties there.

If the blog is private, is there a public RSS feed that IFTTT could see? If so, then the [New Feed Item](https://ifttt.com/channels/feed/triggers/5) on the Feed could be used. Otherwise, the [Blogger](https://ifttt.com/blogger) channel has a new item trigger. I'm not a Blogger user so I can't definitively say that it can work with a private blog. IFTTT needs to be able to see it.

More problematic is the "That" portion of what you're looking for. The [Email](https://ifttt.com/email) channel can only send to *your* email address. The [Gmail](https://ifttt.com/gmail) channel sends a message "from" your Gmail account, but to only one recipient address. So unless you can set it up so that all the people you want to reach can be done so through a single address (Google Groups, perhaps), you're not going to be able to do what you want there, either.